# How to use HITS algorithm to rank pages

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, search-algorithms, information-theory, information-retrieval

I am trying to implement a simple web search engine mechanism with using HITS algorithm. I understand how the algorithm work and produce hubs and authority values for each page. But how can I use this hubs and authorities values to sort web pages? Let's say I have 100 page, their urls, their contents and their hub and authority values. How can I use these to rank pages? I know that there must be tons of way to do that but I mean is there a well-known way to use it like if there is a standard way of doing this?